# Using TensorFlow feature columns in input pipeline

Tags: python, tensorflow, input

I am currently looking to use TensorFlow instead of using numpy for data preparation.
I figured that I could add a few elements to my parse function in my input pipeline.

While I was looking through the documenation, I came across feature columns.
Feature columns seem to help us a bit with data cleaning, if the raw data is used and if the data is passed to the estimator.

I was wondering if there were any functions similar to the feature columns which could do bucketing to the raw data.

What exactly I mean by bucketing is, suppose if I have a dataset like

```
[['num']  #the column headers is for representation only
 [10], 
 [20], 
 [30], 
 [40], 
 [50], 
 [60], 
 [70], 
 [80], 
 [90], 
 [100]]
```

i'll like to create one hot of the above row but in buckets,
The output would look like

```
[['10-50', '51-100'] #the column headers is for representation only
[   1   ,     0   ]
[   1   ,     0   ]
[   1   ,     0   ]
[   1   ,     0   ]
[   1   ,     0   ]
[   0   ,     1   ]
[   0   ,     1   ]
[   0   ,     1   ]
[   0   ,     1   ]
[   0   ,     1   ]]
```

Is there any function which would automatically do this for me?
I know there is a tf.cond function which i could use to implement this with, but it might be cumbersome and length to implement.
i was wondering if there were any plug and play functions for it

related links:
[How feature columns work in tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50334755/how-feature-columns-work-in-tensorflow)
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/feature_columns